# Update MKMapView constraints but keep annotations in same location on screen

Tags: ios, swift

I've got an mkmapview which has annotations on it. I want to resize the mapview (by changing it's height constraint's constant from 200 to 400), but I don't want the map's center coordinate to move at all.

Currently, when the map is resized, the center coordinate moves so that it stays in the center of the map (from (x, 100) to (x, 200) if the map height goes from 200 to 400).

It seems the only solution to this is executing code like this:

```
var coordinate = self.mapView.centerCoordinate
coordinate.latitude += self.mapView.region.span.latitudeDelta * 0.25;
self.mapView.setCenterCoordinate(coordinate, animated: true)
```

This does work, but the issue I'm encountering is mainly with **animation**. I want to update the constraint in an animated fashion as well:

```
mapHeightConstraint.constant = 400
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.35) {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

This results in the map not being animated regardless of whether I animate the constraint before or after I adjust the center.

I'd like both animations to occur simultaneously and take the same amount of time or find another solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @maxhud?